# Show that $3+\omega^2\not=\omega^2+3$ where $\omega$ denotes the least infinite ordinal

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I understand this shouldn't work due to ordinals not being associative, commutative or distributive but the question says to include all the details in my argument. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to expand upon this further outside of stating basic laws of ordinals. I know that

$3+\omega \not= \omega +3$

So is the proof very similar? I'm really not sure how to even begin approaching this.

Comment: $3+\omega^2$ is a limit ordinal (it is in fact equal to $\omega^2$ but this is not really needed), while $\omega^2+3$ is a successor ordinal. Can you prove those two facts?

Comment: Very similar, yes. Note $\omega^2=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\omega n$.